# Why won't my css attribute selector refresh when the property changes values

Tags: css, reactjs

Background:
This is a react web app and I am using traditional css loaded using an import statement.  I am using a css selector on the attribute tab index;  This is for a slider.

Problem:
When the slider changes the view to the new visible element it also adjusts the tab index to zero where the rest of the "cards" are set to tab index -1.  The selectors are working perfectly on the first 3 items that are visible, but once the attribute is changed, it is not reapplied.

Here are my selectors:

```
ul li[tabindex="0"]:first-of-type {
    background-color: #002e55;
}

ul li[tabindex="0"]:first-of-type + li {
    background-color: green;
}

ul li[tabindex="0"]:first-of-type + li + li {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The html is pretty simple and looks like the following:
[image]

If it helps I am using the pure-react-carousel from express-labs for the carousel.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with :

```
ul li[tabindex="0"] {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
ul li[tabindex="0"] + li {
    transform: scale(1);
}
ul li[tabindex="0"] + li + li {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
```

I would still like to see an explanation for why this was happening.